# EmailAddress matching query does not exist when logging in with a superuser account in Django Rest Auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have set up Django Rest Auth with a Custom User Model by extending the Abstract User class. I have enabled mandatory email confirmation. When I create a superuser from the command line, I am unable to log in with that user using Rest Auth's login endpoint. I believe the reason is that Rest Auth uses emailaddress_set to store the emails of the users that have registered and keep a track of whether they have been verified or not. But because a superuser is created from the command line, it does not go through the process of being added to emailaddress_set.

It may be possible to access the table using the console and adding an entry there manually, but it's not the most elegant solution. Does anyone know how to work around this?

This is the error:

```
DoesNotExist at /authentication/login/
EmailAddress matching query does not exist.

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/authentication/login/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Python Executable: /home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path: ['/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend', '/home/caronex/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/201.6668.115/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm', '/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 13:09:16 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'django_filters',
 'drf_yasg',
 'corsheaders',
 'rest_auth',
 'rest_auth.registration',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'users_module',
 'projects_module']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py", line 49, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py", line 103, in post
    self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 234, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 436, in run_validation
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_auth/serializers.py", line 108, in validate
    email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/caronex/Tech/Projects/WebDev/Backend/ieee_project_manager_backend/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 417, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /authentication/login/
Exception Value: EmailAddress matching query does not exist.
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser
```

Here are my settings:

[image: Here are my settings:]

My Custom UserManager

[image: My Custom UserManager]

My CustomUser Model

[image: My CustomUser Model]

Here is where the error originates in the rest_auth library

[image: Here is where the error originates in the rest_auth library]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a temporary fix for this problem. In the `CustomUserManager`, when creating a superuser, we can programmatically create an entry in the `EmailAddress` model that `rest_auth` uses to keep a track of emails. Like so:
[Modification to the CustomUserManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpNoG.png)

Though I believe there has to be a more elegant solution built into `rest_auth` that I am unable to locate.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is a way to set up an "initial" email account in the Django admin dashboard. Create superuser, go to the 127.0.0.1:8000/admin (if you're using this port) and go to Email Addresses, then create an email and assign it to the corresponding superuser you've created previously.

Check the screenshot.

[image]